# Get User of /netonly runas with vba ms access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access App that has tables linked to a SQL Server Database.

This application is for a client that will be using Windows Authentication from their desktop login to authenticate with the SQL server.

I work remotely and have been building the application using runas /netonly /user<> to pass my RDP credentials that I use with the SQL Server to authenticate.

I'm using Environ("USERNAME") to grab the username of the person using the app, which is needed in some cases such as logging comments on one form.  The problem is when using runas /netonly, this returns my local username, when I need it to return the /user I passed through runas.

Is there a way to get the Domain\Username that I passed into runas through code?

Comment: Try `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserDomain` and `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`.

Comment: The above is also more secure against spoofing than Environ("USERNAME").

Comment: You might also consider just querying the SQL server for it (see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-name-transact-sql) if you want to know how). That way you're 100% sure you're using the same name as your SQL server login.